# Login with facebook in android

Tags: android, facebook, android-studio, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-4.0

I want to implement login with facebook in android. When facebook app is installed or not installed it is working good. In short, it is working fine in a facebook App and in a browser but if facebook lite is installed instead of facebook original app then sometimes it is not working and not returned a result. So Is it possible to open login with facebook in the browser if facebook lite is installed?

Answer (score 0):

please refer [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android) link.In this link give you best tutorial and also it's working with facebook app and without facebook app.I did facebook integration from that link

just add this gradle in your build.gradle `compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'` no need to download facebook sdk

Comment: please chack my updated answer

Comment: Thank you @Bhupat Bheda. It is working fine with facebook app and in a browser but it is not working well with facebook lite app.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the Android SDK
2. Get a Facebook App ID, Include the SDK, 
   and Add Key Hashes to Your Profile
3. Enable Single Sign On for Your App

please read a doc

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android

Comment: I had done all this step but you didn't understand my question. It is working fine with facebook app and browser but not working well with facebook lite app.

Comment: You have to explain in detail for users have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

you are using facebook sdk 4.0, that has issue with facebook lite.

compile this sdk:  `compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'`

and also add this in gradle:

```
 jcenter {
            url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"
        }
```

for more information see documentation properly.

Comment: Thanks, @Sagar Chavada for understanding my problem. I will use this in my code and give you an update. I hope it will work.

Comment: I had tried it but still, it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
**Process Login With Facebook**
**Working on Play Store** 

**Link     
     - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.codecube.airbucks&hl=en    
**
**Step 1** Registered your new app? If you didn't, go to https://developers.facebook.com/apps/, click Add a New App in the top right and follow the instructions. **step by step**

**Manifest Permission**
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

**build.Gradle Dependency**
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.8.0' 
    /*compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'*/


                 <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
                            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
                            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
                            android:label="@string/app_name" />
                        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationName"
                            android:value="@string/app_name" />
                        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

                        <provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider1854328631556764"
                            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
                            android:exported="true"/> 

            **Layout Xml Code**
            <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
                    android:id="@+id/login_button"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    />

            **Put own generate facebook Key in String.xml File** 
            <string name="facebook_app_id">1854328631556764</string>
                <string name="fb_login_protocol_scheme">fb1854328631556764</string>

                **MainActivity CODE**
                 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main1);
                        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());
                        AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);   

                        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
                        fbloginButton = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.facebook_button);


                        fbloginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {

                                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                                        int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                                                android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
                                        if (permissionCheck == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                                            //showing dialog to select image
                                            callFacebook();
                                            Log.e("permission", "granted");
                                        } else {
                                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                                                    new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                                                            android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 1);
                                        }
                                    } else {
                                        callFacebook();
                                    }
                            }
                        });
                    }

                 **CAllOnFAcebook**
                    public void callFacebook() {

                        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

                //        LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(MainActivity2.this, Arrays.asList("email"));

                        LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(MainActivity.this, Arrays.asList("public_profile"));

                        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {

                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                                Log.e("keshav","onSuccess called ");
                                GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                                        loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                                        new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onCompleted(
                                                    JSONObject object,
                                                    GraphResponse response) {
                                                // Application code
                                                Log.v("LoginActivityfacebook", response.toString());

                                                try {
                                                    JSONObject data = response.getJSONObject();
                                                    facebookName = data.getString("name");
                                                    facebookEmail = data.getString("email");
                                                    facebookId = data.getString("id");
                                                    facebookLink = data.getString("link");
                                                    facebookLink = facebookLink.replace("https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/", "");
                                                    facebookLink = facebookLink.replace("/", "");
                                                    Log.e("profilelink", "" + facebookLink);
                                                    facebookLink = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + facebookLink + "/picture";

                                                    Log.e("facebookName", "is  ->  " + facebookName);
                                                    Log.e("facebookEmail", "is  ->  " + facebookEmail);
                                                    Log.e("facebookId", "is  ->  " + facebookId);
                                                    Log.e("facebookLink", "is  ->  " + facebookLink);


                                                        Log.e("Keshav","Suceesfully Login "+facebookName);



                                                    } else {
                                                        CommonMethod.showAlert("Intenet Connectivity Failure", MainActivity.this);
                                                    }
                                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                                }
                                            }
                                        });
                                Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                                parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender, birthday,link");
                                request.setParameters(parameters);
                                request.executeAsync();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancel() {
                                // App code
                                Log.i(TAG, "cancelTriggered");
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                                // App code
                                Log.i(TAG, "errorTriggered");
                            }
                        });
                        LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();                //  TODO Add Me Using this previous facebook login id password logout
                    }


                **Process Login With Facebook**
            **Working on Play Store** 

        **Link https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.codecube.airbucks&hl=en**
```